# Oracle: table is mutating

Tags: oracle

I have created a trigger with no errors and I have a mutating table, I have never come across this before, what seem to be the issue?

the following is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows aren't changed immediately, the changes are made row by row, and after each change your trigger is invoked.

When it's invoked - it selects from the same table which is semi-changed. This is inconsistent, thus - oracle prevents you from doing that.

You probably may change it to `FOR EACH STATEMENT` and process the bunch of rows how you want, or even rethink the task (there is a chance you're solving it wrong)

Comment: @Jose David Garcia Llanos: I've added the last phrase as an answer for your comment

Comment: I may be using the wrong plsql to solve my problem, i am very new to this, What i need to do is run a script that checks the stock in hand and if any given product falls below the min_stock then show a message, do i need a cursor, procedure, function? or trigger

Comment: @Jose David Garcia Llanos: update then perform a separated select?

Comment: @Jose David Garcia Llanos: I'm not sure I understand you :-S

Comment: @Jose David Garcia Llanos: Well, I would recommend you to create a function or procedure for that, trigger is definitely not a solution for you