# Oracle: calculating and inserting to other table trigger/procedure

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to calculate some values and adding them to another table.

So I have booking, treatment and invoice. the user books some treatments and then the booking session generates the invoice. I already iserted the invoice insert statements manually, just trying to populate the calculated values in accordance to the number of booking sessions. ps. the treatment price are in the treatment table.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM INVOICE;

    INV_ID|INV_DATETIME                  |INV_SUBTOTAL|INV_DISCOUNT|  INV_TOTAL
----------|------------------------------|------------|------------|-----------
       100|14-NOV-12 09.40.06.918000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       101|18-MAR-12 10.03.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       102|18-MAR-12 10.15.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       103|18-MAR-12 10.55.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       104|18-MAR-12 10.38.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       105|12-JUN-12 15.15.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       106|06-AUG-12 12.13.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       107|04-MAY-12 09.15.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       108|29-NOV-12 13.16.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       109|18-MAR-12 10.37.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       110|21-MAR-12 11.26.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       111|24-APR-12 11.16.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       112|12-MAY-12 10.27.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       113|21-MAY-12 13.33.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       114|18-JAN-12 12.17.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       115|20-JUN-12 11.18.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
       116|09-JUN-12 10.14.00.000000     |        $.00|        $.00|       $.00
```

So i am using the following sql query to calculate the subtotal price for an invoice as many booking sessions can be booked at once, these will appear in the same invoice *..1

```
SQL> COLUMN total FORMAT $99,999.99
SQL> SELECT IV.INV_ID, SUM(TR.TR_PRICE) as Total
  2  FROM BOOKING_SESSION BS, TREATMENT TR, INVOICE IV
  3  WHERE BS.INV_ID = IV.INV_ID
  4  AND BS.BK_TREATMENT = TR.TR_ID
  5  GROUP BY IV.INV_ID
  6  ORDER BY BS.INV_ID ASC;

    INV_ID|      TOTAL
----------|-----------
       100|    $605.00
       101|     $45.00
       102|     $70.00
       103|     $65.00
       104|     $50.00
       105|     $25.00
       106|     $25.00
       107|     $25.00
       108|     $25.00
       109|     $50.00
       110|     $25.00
       111|     $50.00
       112|     $15.00
       113|     $15.00
       114|     $25.00
       115|     $25.00
       116|     $25.00
```

Now i want to grab each value and add it to the `INV_SUBTOTAL`

I tried doing the following but doesnt seem to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INV_SUBTOTAL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BOOKING_SESSION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT 
        (SELECT SUM(TR.TR_PRICE) FROM BOOKING_SESSION BS, TREATMENT TR, INVOICE IV WHERE BS.INV_ID = IV.INV_ID AND BS.BK_TREATMENT = TR.TR_ID)
      INTO :NEW.INV_SUBTOTAL
   FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> SHOW ERROR
Errors for TRIGGER INV_SUBTOTAL:

LINE/COL|ERROR
--------|-----------------------------------------------------------------
4/12    |PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INV_SUBTOTAL'
SQL>
```

Perhaps i am doing it wrong T_T

Here is the data for relating tables;

```
SQL> select * from treatment;

     TR_ID|TR_NAME             |TR_SPECIALIST|   TR_PRICE
----------|--------------------|-------------|-----------
         1|Hair removal        |            1|     $25.00
         2|Hair styling        |            1|     $50.00
         3|Nails               |            1|     $15.00
         4|Botox               |            1|     $30.00
         5|Make up             |            5|     $35.00
         6|Reflexology         |            3|     $25.00
         7|Massage therapy     |            3|     $25.00
         8|Facial care         |            4|     $25.00
         9|Weight loss         |            2|     $40.00
        10|Consultation        |            2|     $20.00

10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from booking_session
  2  where inv_id > 100;

     BK_ID|BK_DATE                       | BK_BOOKER|BK_CUSTOMER|BK_TREATMENT|START_SESSION              |END_SESSION              |STAFFAPPOINTED|   BK_ROOM|    INV_ID
----------|------------------------------|----------|-----------|------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|--------------|----------|----------
         4|18-MAR-12 10.35.00.000000     |         1|          4|          10|20-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 13.00.00.000000     |             1|         4|       109
         5|18-MAR-12 10.36.00.000000     |         1|          4|           4|21-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |             1|         5|       109
         6|18-MAR-12 10.50.00.000000     |         5|          5|           2|20-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |             5|         6|       103
        11|18-MAR-12 10.09.00.000000     |        10|         10|          10|20-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |            10|        10|       102
        12|18-MAR-12 10.12.00.000000     |        10|         10|           6|22-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000     |22-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |            11|        11|       102
        16|18-MAR-12 10.00.00.000000     |        15|         14|          10|20-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |            15|        14|       101
        17|18-MAR-12 10.02.00.000000     |        15|         14|           7|20-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 13.00.00.000000     |            16|        15|       101
        31|21-MAR-12 11.25.00.000000     |         1|          4|           1|24-MAR-12 11.00.00.000000     |24-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |             2|         1|       110
        32|24-APR-12 11.15.00.000000     |         1|          4|           2|26-APR-12 12.00.00.000000     |26-APR-12 13.00.00.000000     |             3|         2|       111
        33|12-MAY-12 10.25.00.000000     |         1|          4|           3|21-MAY-12 13.00.00.000000     |21-MAY-12 14.00.00.000000     |             4|         3|       112
        34|21-MAY-12 13.32.00.000000     |         1|          4|           3|26-MAY-12 15.00.00.000000     |26-MAY-12 16.00.00.000000     |             4|         3|       113
        35|18-JAN-12 12.14.00.000000     |         1|          4|           6|21-JAN-12 11.00.00.000000     |21-JAN-12 12.00.00.000000     |            17|         5|       114
        36|20-JUN-12 11.16.00.000000     |         1|          4|           7|25-JUN-12 11.00.00.000000     |25-JUN-12 12.00.00.000000     |            22|         5|       115
        37|09-JUN-12 10.12.00.000000     |         1|          4|           8|11-JUL-12 11.00.00.000000     |11-JUL-12 12.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       116
        20|18-MAR-12 10.30.00.000000     |        15|         17|           7|20-MAR-12 09.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 10.00.00.000000     |            16|        17|       104
        39|18-MAR-12 10.35.00.000000     |         1|         17|           8|25-MAR-12 13.00.00.000000     |25-MAR-12 14.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       104
        40|12-JUN-12 15.11.00.000000     |         1|         17|           8|11-JUL-12 11.00.00.000000     |11-JUL-12 12.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       105
        41|06-AUG-12 12.13.00.000000     |         1|         17|           8|11-AUG-12 11.00.00.000000     |11-AUG-12 12.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       106
        42|04-MAY-12 09.15.00.000000     |         1|         17|           8|28-JUN-12 11.00.00.000000     |28-JUN-12 12.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       107
        43|29-NOV-12 13.16.00.000000     |         1|         17|           8|01-DEC-12 11.00.00.000000     |01-DEC-12 12.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       108
        44|18-MAR-12 10.53.00.000000     |         5|          5|           3|20-MAR-12 13.00.00.000000     |20-MAR-12 14.00.00.000000     |             6|         7|       103
        38|18-MAR-12 10.13.00.000000     |         1|         10|           8|25-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000     |25-MAR-12 13.00.00.000000     |            24|         5|       102
```

Here is the bit of the ERD related to this question.

[image: erd2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to update the `INV_SUBTOTAL` column in `INVOICE` for a particular `INV_ID` with the `TOTAL` that is computed in the second query, you would need an `UPDATE` statement.  My guess (since I don't know what the `TREATMENT` or `BOOKING_SESSION` tables look like or what data they contain) is that you want a correlated update that looks something like

```
UPDATE invoice inv
   SET inv_subtotal = (SELECT SUM(tr.tr_price)
                         FROM treatment tr,
                              booking_session bs
                        WHERE bs.inv_id = inv.inv_id
                          AND bs.bk_treatment = tr.tr_id)
```

A trigger on `BOOKING_SESSION` won't do anything unless you actually update (or insert into) the `BOOKING_SESSION` table.  A row-level trigger on `BOOKING_SESSION` also cannot, in general, query the `BOOKING_SESSION` table without generating a [mutating table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445477/oracle-table-is-mutating) that we discussed in one of your questions a couple of days ago.  And the `:new` record in a trigger is based on the table the trigger is defined on-- you can only reference columns that are part of the `BOOKING_SESSION` table.  You can't reference `:new.inv_subtotal` unless `INV_SUBTOTAL` is a column in the table you've defined the trigger on.

In the real world, there would also be a serious denormalization problem here.  Storing aggregated data separately from the row-level data violates basic normalization and will almost certainly lead to data quality issues where the aggregate data doesn't match the lower-level data that is stored in the `TREATMENT` table.  Since this is just a homework assignment, perhaps your professor wants you to ignore that issue but it's something you'd want to be very sensitive to in the real world.

Comment: Hi Justin, seems my teachers never mentioned these kind of issues, what you just mentioned made me realise an issue in my db, if the prices of the treatments change then the invoice will also change and this is an issue since we dont want to change what the customer actually paid for historic purposes and data consistency. 

my question then would be, what is the better way of calculating the invoice?

Comment: since the values in the invoice should be automatically updated, is it better to create a trigger that when a new booking is made or edited then it inserts/updates the records in the invoice table?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - In the real world, the best way depends.  Frequently, you would simply not store the total anywhere.  You would create a function that computed the invoice amount (by summing the `tr.tr_price` rows) and use that.  If you want to store the invoice amount, you would be storing the amount of the invoice that was actually sent which you would expect to remain constant even if the prices on all the treatments changed.  That would, of course, mean taht you expect the summary and detail information to be out of sync.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - Depending on what sort of historical information you need to maintain, you might also capture line items for each invoice for each treatment that stored the price of the treatment at the time of the service which would not change over time.

Comment: thanks Justin, i just realised i can model the db a little different, If i have a linker table between the `booking_session` and the `treatment` and then just call the linker table treatment_sessions and change the booking_session to booking so treatment_sessions will include the different treatments booked at a particular point in time, which of the tables will generate the invoice then? the linker or the booking table.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos - I'm not sure what your existing data model looks like, I'm not sure what your new data model is, and I'm not sure exactly what all the entities in your data model are so it's hard to suggest which of the tables would be involved in generating the invoice.  It may also depend on how and when you generate the invoice (I may book an appointment when a treatment is $10, show up when the treatment is on sale for $8, and then have the invoice generated at the end of the month when the treatment is now $12).